# Why long execution time of PHP scripts on new server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, imagemagick

I have a server that has 2 quad core processors (2.4 GHz, 16GB RAM). I have a some PHP scripts that run under very heavy load. Most of these scripts do few things:

1. Fetch Data from database (just a single row, from a small table)
2. Fetch Data from other server (mainly Facebook)
3. Upload a small photo
4. Update Database table (this table is very heavily used, and number of rows grows very quickly, almost 2 rows per second)

The problem is that, the scripts are taking too much time to execute. I had a server previously which has lower configuration (one quad core processor, 6GB RAM), but scripts took 4-5 sec to complete. But now, execution time is 30-40sec, even more.

HOW I MEASURE EXECUTION TIME? I measure `microtime()` at start of script and end of script and subtract them. I just needed a rough estimate.

SERVER CONFIGURATION: Here are some parameters set in apache config:

```
server_limit = 350
max_chlid = 350
keep_alive = off
```

Other Characteristics:
1. When server is not under heavy load, execution time is very small
2. Previous server took very less time to execute, even under heavy load

I don't know what else details should I include. Please ask me, and I will post them here.

### What should I do to improve this?

Update:

I have figured out the problem is with ImageMagick library. I googled and tried few soution like disabling OpenMP. But it hasn't helped much

Comment: Dude what kind of database tables are you using, MyIsam or innodb. Whats you mySQL version.

Comment: I have figured out that the problem is due to ImageMagic library which is used to generate images. There is not much calculation intensive processing, still its slow. I sould try and installing it again.

Answer (score 3):

I'm suggesting to do profiling with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and then analyze it with software like [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html). Then you will know what's taking time.

Comment: You should also look at the settings of the DBs, When the transistion to the new server was done, were all the DB's properly tuned in terms of caching, memory and query limits, internal query caches - these things make a *huge* difference, especially if the DBA knew what he was doing. Also, have the tables been properly anazlyzed after the server change? Your indexes may well be garbage at the moment.

Comment: @Fluffeh thanks, i am trying your suggetions. instead of measuring end time right at bottom, i am trying to measuring it at different places in the script. i will post what i get

Answer (score 1):

This could have many reasons:

1. Are your queries "slow"?
2. Is the server configuration right?
3. Has it a slow bandwidth?
4. Is MySql-Server configuration right?
5. What is the format of the table you insert?
6. Is something else (a cronjob e.g.) killing the database?

I would post this as a comment, but unfortunatly i can't please clear up those questions and tell what you find out ;)

Comment: Your asking the right questions, I don't understand why people are giving you the thumbs down buddy!!!!

Comment: because this should be a comment not an answer and believe me i would comment if i could but i lack the xp to do so

Comment: server ahs 100mbps port. i have run mysqltuner.pl and included the suggestions in my.cnf. i have a few cron jobs, but they run only a few times a day.

Answer (score 0):

I would start to decouple the problem. Test each action (fetch from db, fetch from fb, upload, etc.) separately.

At the same time check if all the components of your new server env are the same (packages, version, config, etc.) as before.

Comment: i have figured out the problem is wirh ImageMagick library. I googled and tried few soution like disabling OpenMP. But it hasn't helped much